# JMeter 14 Hour Soak Test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to run a 14 hour soak test in JMeter.  Need to hit a few pages with around 100 users an hour - so nothing crazy.

What would be an appropriate way to set this up in terms of ramp up period etc?

Answer (score 1):

- "100 users an hour" doesn't make a lot of sense, if you need to mimic 100 users for 14 hours you need to configure [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) like:

  [image]
- with regards to ramp-up - as per JMeter documentation:

  > The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
  >
  > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
  >
  > **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.**

  the point is to increase the load **gradually** so you can ramp-up i.e. for first hour and then hold the load for remaining 13 hours if nothing bad happens during the ramp-up phase
- Also make sure to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) when it comes to:

  - [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
  - embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts)
  - [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
  - [think times](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9)

Comment: If you specify infinite loop, then you hit the request infinite times(practically based on the system threads).